# attribute starts with selector ,working for first input field(not for others)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i am having an issue with attribute starts with selector ,i have tried to do validation of multiple fields ,having dynamic ids ,but not succeed .

below is what i tried so far .

i have seen other suggestion in So,but unable to made it.

```js
  $("input[id^='product-unit-price-']").keydown(function (event) {
    });
```

Html

```html
 <input type="text"  class="form-control pro-input valfields" id="product-unit-price-<?php echo $id;?>" name="unit_price[]" onblur="getTotalPrice(<?php echo $id;?>)" required="">
```

here id is dynamic like

product-unit-price-0

product-unit-price-1

product-unit-price-2

product-unit-price-3

and so on..

here its working for only the first id (product-unit-price-0) ,but not for rests.
Its all the things.

Suggest me.

thank you.

Comment: where is the rest of things inside handler?

Comment: i have given this part only.

Comment: the problem is not with the selector. `$("input[id^='product-unit-price-']")` will select all `input` elements that has an `id attribute` that starts with "product-unit-price-". Without rest of your code, we can only make guesses as to what you might have done wrong. Share rest of your code.

Comment: @sradha : I think problem lies in the rest of the code

Comment: yes ,that rest parts are coming in ajax load ,first field loads when page is loading ,
i just changed some few things,now got it.

thank you.

Comment: @PranavCBalan  ,got  it :) :)

Comment: working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sameer_ngl/r4nbuujw/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using `$("input[id^='product-unit-price-']")` to refer the element inside the handler in this case while applying `val()` method which always return the value of the first element, not the element which is fired the event. In such case use `$(this)` to refer the element where `this` refers to the dom object of event fired element.

```
$("input[id^='product-unit-price-']").keydown(function (event) {
    // refer element by `$(this)`    
})
```

---

**FYI :** It's always better to provide a common class for the group of the element and select based on that which is the better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Why you not go with class selector?

```
$(".form-control.pro-input.valfields").keydown(function (event) {
// your logics here
}
```

Because from class selector you can select set of same class group elements and apply event on each element of set.